# Copy only certain folders while using csv data powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, copy

I don't want to copy all the folder how do I tell it not to copy certain folders like ( appData and application Data )

csv file contain:

```
FullName                             Name
\\computer6587\c$\Users\A2846      A2846
\\computer6587\c$\Users\B2846      B2846
```

Code:

```
Import-Csv -path C:\computer6587-PREP.csv | foreach {Copy-item -recurse $_.FullName "c:\backup" -Force -Verbose}
```

Comment: Please format your question properly. What is the content of your CSV file? If you don't want to copy certain folders, exclude them from the list of objects to be copied..

Comment: csv file contain:

FullName Name \computer6587\c$\Users\A2846 A2846 \computer6587\c$\Users\B2846 B2846

Comment: if is not too much trouble can you please help me with this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65346076/match-file-with-folder-directory-and-insert-each-file-found-to-its-folder-direct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I made a helper function some time ago:

```
function Copy-ExcludeFolders {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [ValidateScript({ $_ | Test-Path -PathType Container })]
        [string]$SourceFolder,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Destination,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [string[]]$Exclude,

        [switch]$Force
    )

    # create a regex of the folders to exclude
    # each folder will be Regex Escaped and joined together with the OR symbol '|'
    $notThese = ($Exclude | ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

    Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Recurse -File |
         Where-Object{ $_.DirectoryName -notmatch $notThese } |
         ForEach-Object {
            $target = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($SourceFolder.Length)
            if (!(Test-Path -Path $target -PathType Container)) {
                Write-Verbose "Creating folder '$target'"
                $null = New-Item -Path $target -ItemType Directory
            }
            Write-Verbose "Copying '$($_.FullName)' to '$target'"
            $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $target -Force:$Force
         }
}
```

With that function in place at the top of your script, use it like this:

```
$exclude = 'appData', 'application Data'  # add more folders to exclude here
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\computer6587-PREP.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-ExcludeFolders -SourceFolder $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\backup' -Exclude $exclude -Force -Verbose
}
```

---

If you want the users data to be copied to a certain subfolder in the destination path, then I suggest you also use the `Name` column you have in the csv.

```
$exclude = 'appData', 'application Data'  # add more folders to exclude here
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\computer6587-PREP.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $dest = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.Name
    # just to see if the input from the csv will give you the desired source and destination paths:
    Write-Host "Copying files from '$($_.FullName)' to folder '$dest'"
    Copy-ExcludeFolders -SourceFolder $_.FullName -Destination $dest -Exclude $exclude -Force -Verbose
}
```

---

**EDIT**

We should not add so many comments to a question.
This is how I tested the above code and the result shows it is exactly as expected.

I used this for input csv called `Source-PREP.csv` (your filename will be different of course)

```
FullName,Name,LastWriteTime
D:\Test\Users\H107371a,H107371a,11/25/2020 7:19
D:\Test\Users\m763671,m763671,12/3/2020 9:12
D:\Test\Users\W575288,W575288,9/18/2020 15:23
D:\Test\Users\W575288a,W575288a,9/18/2020 15:23
```

Then I created a few dummy users in my D:\Test path, with 'appData' and 'application Data' folders aswell as some subfolders that should be copied:

```
D:\TEST\USERS
+---H107371a
|   |   test.txt
|   |
|   +---appData
|   |       mustnotcopy.txt
|   |
|   +---application Data
|   |       donotcopy.txt
|   |
|   +---Folder1
|   |       blah.txt
|   |       somepicture.jpg
|   |
|   \---Folder2
|           myvideo.mp4
|           whatever.txt
|
+---m763671
|   |   test.txt
|   |
|   +---appData
|   |       mustnotcopy.txt
|   |
|   +---application Data
|   |       donotcopy.txt
|   |
|   +---FolderA
|   |       blah1.txt
|   |       somepicture1.jpg
|   |
|   \---FolderB
|           myvideo1.mp4
|           whatever1.txt
|
+---W575288
|   |   test.txt
|   |
|   +---appData
|   |       mustnotcopy.txt
|   |
|   +---application Data
|   |       donotcopy.txt
|   |
|   +---FolderX
|   |       blah2.txt
|   |       somepicture2.jpg
|   |
|   \---FolderY
|           myvideo2.mp4
|           whatever2.txt
|
\---W575288a
    |   test.txt
    |
    +---Another-Folder
    |       myvideo3.mp4
    |       whatever3.txt
    |
    +---appData
    |       mustnotcopy.txt
    |
    +---application Data
    |       donotcopy.txt
    |
    \---Some-Folder
            blah3.txt
            somepicture3.jpg
```

Next, I ran the code

```
$exclude     = 'appData', 'application Data'  # add more folders to exclude here
$destination = "\\<myMachine>\D$\CopiedProfiles"

Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Source-PREP.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $dest = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.Name
    # just to see if the input from the csv will give you the desired source and destination paths:
    Write-Host "Copying files from '$($_.FullName)' to folder '$dest'"
    Copy-ExcludeFolders -SourceFolder $_.FullName -Destination $dest -Exclude $exclude -Force -Verbose
}
```

and this is the result after the copy:

```
D:\COPIEDPROFILES
+---H107371a
|   |   test.txt
|   |
|   +---Folder1
|   |       blah.txt
|   |       somepicture.jpg
|   |
|   \---Folder2
|           myvideo.mp4
|           whatever.txt
|
+---m763671
|   |   test.txt
|   |
|   +---FolderA
|   |       blah1.txt
|   |       somepicture1.jpg
|   |
|   \---FolderB
|           myvideo1.mp4
|           whatever1.txt
|
+---W575288
|   |   test.txt
|   |
|   +---FolderX
|   |       blah2.txt
|   |       somepicture2.jpg
|   |
|   \---FolderY
|           myvideo2.mp4
|           whatever2.txt
|
\---W575288a
    |   test.txt
    |
    +---Another-Folder
    |       myvideo3.mp4
    |       whatever3.txt
    |
    \---Some-Folder
            blah3.txt
            somepicture3.jpg
```

If you have different results, then please correct your input csv so the file has the correct SourceFolder in column `FullName` and the correct destination subfolder name to create the target folder in parameter `Destination`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225985/discussion-on-answer-by-theo-copy-only-certain-folders-while-using-csv-data-powe).