# match file with folder directory and insert each file found to its folder directory

Tags: powershell, object, foreach, merge

code:

```
c:\Users\H107371a\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
c:\Users\m763671\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
c:\Users\W575288\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

csv file contain:

```
Full Name Name
c:\      H107371a
c:\      m763671
c:\      W575288
```

```
$source = Read-Host -Prompt 'Insert SOURCE computer'
$destination = Read-Host -Prompt 'Insert DESTINATION computer'
$InvoiceList = Import-CSV -Path C:\$source-PREP.csv
 for each($list in $InvoiceList){
$Name=$($list.name)
Get-Child Item -Path 'C:\' -Filter *.cmd | where {$_.Name -like "*$name*" } |
 Set-Content -Path ('C:\{0}-Config.cmd' -f $_) -Force}
 Copy-Item -Destination |  where {$_.Name -like "*$name*" } "\\$destination\c$\Users\{0}\App Data\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\" -Force
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not quite sure, I think you want to:

- read a csv where the Name column must correspond to the name of a .cmd file in your C:\ drive
- If such a file is found, make a copy of that under a different name on a remote computer

For that you can use the following code:

```
$source      = Read-Host -Prompt 'Insert SOURCE computer'
$destination = Read-Host -Prompt 'Insert DESTINATION computer'

$InvoiceList = Import-CSV -Path "C:\$source-PREP.csv"

# loop through the Names column from the CSV
foreach($userName in $InvoiceList.Name) {
    # try and get a .cmd file with a basename like the name from the CSV
    $file = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Filter '*.cmd' | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -like "*$userName*" } | Select-Object -First 1
    if ($file) {
        # create a new file name for the copy
        $newName = '{0}-Config.cmd' -f $userName
        $target  = '\\{0}\c$\Users\{1}\App Data\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\{2}' -f $destination, $userName, $newName
        Write-Host "Copying file '$($file.FullName)' to '$target'"
        $file | Copy-Item -Destination $target -WhatIf
    }
}
```

As you can see, Copy-Item can copy a file with a new name directly.

The `-WhatIf` switch is for your own safety. **With** that, nothing is copies, the console just shows you what *would* happen. If you are satisfied all looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf` switch and run the code again.

Comment: @EnriqueTellez Is this what you are after? please let us know if this works for you or not (and if not, what problems you have with it)